# Default text is black-on-black for awesome window manager

Tags: awesome

When running gthumb under the awesome window manager the default text is black-on-black.  As you can see from the attached image I can see the the highlighted text but I can't see any other text in the menu.

[image: Black-on-black menus for gthumb]

The default text for the terminal is also black on black. I can fix it by de-selecting `Use colors from system theme`.

This doesn't happen when I use the "Ubuntu" window manager.  I can see the terminal using system colours and I can see all the menu items in gthumb.

I didn't previously have this problem in awesome.  I believe it happened after I did an `apt-get autoremove`.

How can I fix this?